# Passing two parameters in yii2 ajax request using jquery to a controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a link when pressed it requests a page from a controller via render ajax, Previously i used to pass only the id but now i would like to pass an extra parameter to the controller, how do i achieve this,
This is what i have tried

This is the link' which only passes a single parameter to the controller

```
Html::a('click me', ['#'],
['value' => Url::to('checktruck?id='.$model->id), //this is where the param is passed 
'id' => 'perform']);
```

This is the controller code expecting 2 parameters:

```
public function actionChecktruck($id,$category)  //it expects 2 parameters from above link
{
     $truckdetails = Truck::find()->where(['id' =>$id])->one();

    if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
      $checklistperform = new TodoTruckChecklist();
        $truck = Truck::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
        $checklistperform->truck_id=$id;
        $checklistperform->registered_by=Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $checklistperform->save();
        $truck->update();

        var_dump($checklistperform->getErrors());
        //var_dump($truck->getErrors());
    }
    else {
        $truckcategory = Checklist::find()->where(['truck_category'=>$truckdetails->truck_category])->andWhere(['checklist_category'=>$category])->all();
        return $this->renderAjax('truckyard/_checklistform', [
            'truckcategory' => $truckcategory,'truckvalue'=>$id,
        ]);

    }

}
```

This is my jquery code of another button that depends on the above controller during post request

```
$("#postbutn").click(function(e) {

   $.post("checktruck?id="+truckid,  //here i would like to pass 2 params
                {checked:checked,unchecked:unchecked,truckid:truckid}
            )
 }
```

This is the jquery code when there is no post

How can i pass an extra parameter in the link or even the $.post request for the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as you are using JQuery ajax to submit the form, there is no need to set value for the link

```
Html::a('click me', ['#'],['id' => 'perform']);
```

using this id you can submit the request as follows

```
$this->registerJs("$('#perform').click(function(event){

event.preventDefault(); // to avoid default click event of anchor tag

$.ajax({
    url: '".yii\helpers\Url::to(["your url here","id"=>$id,"param2"=>param2])."',        
    success: function (data) {
           // you response here
        },
      });
});");
```

There is no need to mention method attribute as 'POST', you want to send through GET method

And finally in your controller, you need to accept parameters as follows

```
public function actionChecktruck()  //it expects 2 parameters from above link
{
     $id = Yii::$app->request->queryParams['id'];
     $param2 = Yii::$app->request->queryParams['param2'];

     $truckdetails = Truck::find()->where(['id' =>$id])->one();

    if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
      $checklistperform = new TodoTruckChecklist();
        $truck = Truck::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
        $checklistperform->truck_id=$id;
        $checklistperform->registered_by=Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $checklistperform->save();
        $truck->update();

        var_dump($checklistperform->getErrors());
        //var_dump($truck->getErrors());
    }
    else {
        $truckcategory = Checklist::find()->where(['truck_category'=>$truckdetails->truck_category])->andWhere(['checklist_category'=>$category])->all();
        return $this->renderAjax('truckyard/_checklistform', [
            'truckcategory' => $truckcategory,'truckvalue'=>$id,
        ]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,
In View file

```
$this->registerJs("$('#postbutn').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: '".yii\helpers\Url::to(["u r URL"])."',        
    method: 'POST',       
    data: {id:id, truckid:truckid },
    success: function (data) {
        },
      });
});");
```